# Need help understanding inner try catch and outer try catch

Tags: java

I have picked up some code that was handed on from me by another developer. It has a database call that has an inner try block without a catch and then an outer try block with a catch.

I'd like some help with an understanding of what it means. Because there is no catch on the inner try block does that mean that any exceptions in the database layer are being ignored? And is there outer try catch block only catching the errors from getConnection and also closeStatement?

thanks for your help with this.

```
public int doKeywordSearch (
    String username,
    String sessionId,
    String[] keywords, 
    String status) throws RetekServiceException {

    int totalRecords = 0;
    Connection connection = null;
    CallableStatement callStmt = null;
    try {
        connection = DaoUtils.getDataSource().getConnection();      
        try {   
            callStmt = connection.prepareCall(DaoConstants.ITEM_SEARCH_KEYWORD_SQL);
            callStmt.setString(1, username);                                                    // p_vUsername
            callStmt.setString(2, sessionId);                                                   // p_vSid
            callStmt.setString(3, StringUtils.clean(keywords.length > 0 ? keywords[0] : null)); // p_vKeyword1 
            callStmt.setString(4, StringUtils.clean(keywords.length > 1 ? keywords[1] : null)); // p_vKeyword2
            callStmt.setString(5, StringUtils.clean(keywords.length > 2 ? keywords[2] : null)); // p_vKeyword3 
            callStmt.setString(6, StringUtils.clean(keywords.length > 3 ? keywords[3] : null)); // p_vKeyword4
            callStmt.setString(7, StringUtils.clean(keywords.length > 4 ? keywords[4] : null)); // p_vKeyword5
            callStmt.setString(8, status);                                                      // p_vStatus
            callStmt.registerOutParameter(9, OracleTypes.INTEGER);              
            callStmt.execute();
            totalRecords = callStmt.getInt(9);
            connection.commit();
        }
        finally {
            DaoUtils.closeStatement(callStmt);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException e) {
        DaoUtils.doRollback(connection, e);
    }
    catch(NamingException e) {          
        throw new RetekServiceException("Could not do keyword search.", e);
    }
    finally {
        DaoUtils.closeConnection(connection);
    }                   
    return totalRecords;
}
```

Comment: The inner `try/finally` is allowing the exception to passed out to the outter `try/catch/finally`.  Have a look at [The finally block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for more details about how that works

Comment: Also, if you're using Java 7+, you should have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `try{} catch(){} finally {}` doesn't require both `catch` and `finally`, only one of them. How it works, when an exception handled by one of the `catch` blocks is thrown inside the `try` then that `catch` block is called. Otherwise the **exception** is propagated up as usual (where exactly it gets propagated I'll explain in a minute). The **finally** block is called almost always no matter if an exception occurred or not (please check the Java specification for rare occasions when a finally block might get skipped).

If in the **inner** `try` block an exception occurs and there is no `catch` clause that could handle it then the **outer** `try/catch` will try to handle it with ad appropriate `catch` clause of the **outer** `try/catch`, otherwise if no such `catch` clause exists in the **outer** `try/catch` then the exception will get propagated up (to the method that called this method or all the way up the JVM).

Actually the above example makes not much sense, you could just as well put the statements inside the outer finally block...

Also as others pointed out if you're using java7 and your `connection` implements `AutoCloseable` you can go with `try-with-resources` which will automatically take care of resource closing and you won't have to write the `finally` manually anymore.

Answer (score 2):

The exceptions from the inner try/catch block are not ignored, they are thrown up the chain to the outer try/catch block (and possibly beyond).

The purpose of the inner try/catch block would appear to be to ensure the statement is closed (in the finally clause) should any statement within the try block fail.

Answer (score 2):

The inner example is a `try` and `finally` block (note the absence of `catch`). A `finally` block is guaranteed to be invoked regardless of an `Exception`. But, I would recomment a [`try-with-resources` Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

```
try (CallableStatement callStmt = connection.prepareCall(
        DaoConstants.ITEM_SEARCH_KEYWORD_SQL)) {
    // ...
}
```

Which is another way to guarantee that `callStmt` will be `close`(d).

See also [JLS-14.20.2. Execution of `try-finally` and `try-catch-finally`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

Answer (score 1):

The outer try-block will still catch exceptions from the inner try-block. The inner try-block is there to make sure `DaoUtils.closeStatement(callStmt);` is invoked.